# Remove Stock Status if Price = 0 in Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, php, price, stock, inventory

Is there a way to hide the Out Of Stock message for products with $0 as a price only? I realize that the saleable quantity can be hidden in `Go to Stores > Configuration > Catalog > Inventory > Stock Options` but I believe this needs to be done at the code level. I am not sure where to start.

Comment: Do you have this( Go to Stores > Configuration > Catalog > Inventory > Stock Options > Display Out of Stock Products) option enable in your admin panel?

Comment: You can turn off  "Manage Stock" for such products

Comment: I only want to hide the Out of Stock messages for items that are $0. Not hide all Out of Stock messages.